# Почему не срабатывает событие скролла?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется такой компонент:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(1);
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(1);
    }
  }



  render() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Почему нигде не срабатывает событие скролла?

Answer (score 1):

Срабатывает!

Вообще то у вас ошибка.

Внутри метода `render`.Ошибка в том что метод рендер *должен возвращать элемент React*.А у вас там никакого ключевого слово `return` нету.Потому и ошибка и соответсвенно код не работает и событие не вызывается.

И небольшое замечание внутри `constructor`-а я бы не советовал ничего вот так вызывать.

Вот рабочий код

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(1);
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.onscroll = function() {
      console.log(1);
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Return something from here</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом :)

Там есть Return, просто я не добавлял его в пример кода. Суть в том, что события scroll не может быть, т.к. прокрутка идет целыми экранами в 100vh из-за плагина. Нужно использовать другое событие.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi в вопросе не было слова про плагина и целых экранах.И пример надо было добавить полностью вообще желательно воспроизводимый.

Comment: Там целое приложение на React, сделать воспроизводимый пример очень тяжело.